# Why is reflect Type.Implements() so much slower than a type assertion?

Tags: go, reflection

I'm trying to efficiently test whether an interface{} implements a given function and my solution is to create an interface with just this function and then check whether the interface{} implements this single function interface. The two options here seem to be either using reflection or a type assertion. Both seem to have identical behaviour however there is a large speed difference.

Looking at the code for Value.Implements() it does a linear scan over the functions defined on the value and compares them against the interface.
The type assertion however just seems to do a constant time comparison (independent of the number of functions in the interface).

Is there a reason why Implements() doesn't just do a type assertion?

Benchmark:

```
package benchmarks

import (
    "reflect"
    "testing"
)

type ITest interface {
    Foo()
}

type Base struct{}

func (Base) A() {}
func (Base) B() {}
func (Base) C() {}
func (Base) D() {}
func (Base) E() {}
func (Base) F() {}
func (Base) G() {}
func (Base) H() {}
func (Base) I() {}
func (Base) J() {}

var Interface = reflect.TypeOf((*ITest)(nil)).Elem()

func BenchmarkReflection(b *testing.B) {
    var iface interface{}
    iface = Base{}
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        if reflect.TypeOf(iface).Implements(Interface) {
            b.FailNow()
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkAssertion(b *testing.B) {
    var iface interface{}
    iface = Base{}
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        if _, ok := iface.(ITest); ok {
            b.FailNow()
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
go test -run=XXX -bench=. so_test.go
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkReflection-8           10000000                  208 ns/op
BenchmarkAssertion-8            200000000                9.24 ns/op
PASS
ok      command-line-arguments  5.115s
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Type assertion in Go relies on a function called [runtime.assertE2I2](https://golang.org/src/runtime/iface.go?s=12130:12194#L505). If you look into the code, you'll notice it relies on `getitab` which in turn relies on `additab` (in the same file).

Now, the actual logic of checking if the given type implements an interface inside of `additab` is exactly the same as `Implements` in `reflect` - a linear search, which is even pointed out in this comment:

```
// both inter and typ have method sorted by name,
// and interface names are unique,
// so can iterate over both in lock step;
// the loop is O(ni+nt) not O(ni*nt).
```

However, the difference is that `additab` actually utilises caching - the result of the type assertion is stored in a hash map, so subsequent type assertions for the same type will run in constant time, which is why you're seeing a huge difference in performance.

Comment: Is there a reason why Implements() doesn't do caching? It suggests it's expecting that whether or not something implements an interface can change (however if this were true then surely the type assertion caching would be incorrect?)

Comment: Because reflection is slow anyway.

Comment: @bradleyjkemp, I'd recommend to refer to the "Computing the Itable" section [here](https://research.swtch.com/interfaces). My guess to answer your comment is: even though type asserts/switches and assigning a value of a concrete type to a variable of an interface type might require computing a new itable for that type at runtime, the compiler presumes there could be only a finite number of such calculations in a sensible program—simply because Go programs can't change itself at runtime…

Comment: @bradleyjkemp …and that's what sets on-the-fly itab computations done by the runtime apart from using the `reflect` package: the latter can be used in arbitrary non-perdictable ways on anything to assert anything. So while in the former case computing the itabs and caching them can be viewed as sort-of just-in-time compilations—amending the regular AoT compilation,—using the `reflect` package is a higher-level and inherently more arbitrary action.

Comment: I feel the question of "why" is not really something we can answer, apart from speculating - perhaps [Go's issue tracker](https://github.com/golang/go/issues) is a better place to raise it? That said, I agree with @kostix on all points - it's far more likely to have a lot of type assertions than a lot of reflection calls. The hash map helps when you expect a lot of calls, but also adds constant overhead which is more noticeable when you have few - and you're not expected to have more than a few calls to reflection.